# Get and post data to a page in facebook using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social

I am trying to access facebook api from spring boot for first time and have hit a wall appreciate any help in the prospect.

I'm trying to get and post data to a page but unable to do using spring boot but its working using graph api.

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/fb")
public class FBController {

    private FBService fbService;

    @Autowired
    public FBController(FBService fbService) {
        this.fbService = fbService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/getFacebookAuthorizeUrl")
    public String getFacebookAuthorizeUrl(){
        return fbService.getFacebookAuthorizeUrl();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/facebook")
    public void getAccessToken(@RequestParam String code){
        fbService.getAccessToken(code);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/userfeed")
    public PagedList<Post> getUserFeed(){
      return fbService.getUserFeed();
    }
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/message")
    public void postMessage(@RequestParam String message){
        fbService.postMessage(message);
    }
```

Service

```
public interface FBService {

    public String getFacebookAuthorizeUrl();
    public void getAccessToken(String code);   
    public PagedList<Post>  getUserFeed();    
    public void postMessage(String message);
}
```

ServiceImpl

```
@Component
public class FBLocalService implements FBService{

    String accessToken;

    @Value("${spring.social.facebook.app-id}")
    private String facebookAppId;

    @Value("${spring.social.facebook.app-secret}")
    private String facebookSecretId;

    @Value("${redirect.url}")
    private String redirectUrl;

    private  FacebookConnectionFactory createConnection(){
        return new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookAppId,facebookSecretId);
    }

    @Override
    public String getFacebookAuthorizeUrl() {
        OAuth2Parameters params = new OAuth2Parameters();
        params.setRedirectUri(redirectUrl);
        params.setScope("email");
        return createConnection().getOAuthOperations().buildAuthenticateUrl(params);
    }

   
    @Override
    public void getAccessToken(String code) {
        accessToken = createConnection().getOAuthOperations().exchangeForAccess(code,redirectUrl,null).getAccessToken();
    }

 @Override
    public PagedList<Post> getUserFeed() {        
        return new FacebookTemplate(accessToken).feedOperations().getFeed();
    }

@Override
    public void postMessage(String message) {
        new FacebookTemplate(accessToken).pageOperations().post(new PagePostData(message));
    }
```

while accessing the `getUserFeed()` no feeds are returned its an empty object and `postMessage()` gives error  "The user is not an administrator of the page with ID Test".

Comment: Don't use Spring Social, it has been dormant and archived years ago. Just use the plain Facebook rest api instead.

Comment: hello M.Deinum, Plain Facebook rest api means restfb ?

Comment: Just the rest endpoints exposed by facebook.